# .change() not triggered in IE 6,7,8 on DropDownList - JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to bind a change event to a dropdownlist.  Works great in chrome and FF but it doesn't fire in IE.  I saw a few other posts about this but they were asking about radio buttons and the suggestion was to use .click(), which obviously doesnt work for a DDL.

Does IE6,7,8 not support .change()?  What am I doing wrong / whats the best way to fix it?  IE8 is the requirement, but itd be nice if it worked in IE7 too.

```
       $('#<%=DropDownListFriends.ClientID %>').live('change', function() {
            if ($('#<%=DropDownListFriends.ClientID %>').val().length > 0) {
               //DoStuff()
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please include a live demo?

Comment: I'm confused. You said you are doing an on change but the code reflects a .click (Live('click'...))

Could you please correct the code and show the .change snippet?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Yea, that should say 'change' - copied the wrong block.  That was a desperation attempt in hopes it would magically do what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encounter that problem... I use $().click instead...

This what i did so that it's doesn't trigger as soon i clicked it..

```
 $("#dropdown").click(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "")
       // do something
 }
```

The trigger will be executed if the user really select on the list that has value...

Hope it helps...

Comment: +1 but `if($(this).val() != "")` can also be just `if(!$(this).val())` because `alert(!"")​` alerts `true`...

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your jQuery statement in a `$(document).ready(...)` function?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   // Add your change handler binding to here...
   $('#<%=DropDownListFriends.ClientID %>').live('change', function() {
       if ($('#<%=DropDownListFriends.ClientID %>').val().length > 0) {
           //DoStuff()
        }
    });
});
```

IE may be taking longer to load the page and the page may not be "ready" yet.

Answer (score 0):

[onchange on dropdowns is buggy in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html#t05). Personally I switched to .click and that worked for me on a dropdown list. But in the [jQuery comments to .change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) there was a suggestion to use:

```
$(element).change(function() { doChange(); }).attr("onchange", function() { doChange(); });
```

or to use .blur

Good luck!

Comment: .click doesn't work at all.  As soon as you click on the list it triggers it.  It doesn't let you select anything.  Works great for checkboxes and radiobuttons tho.